# Will I feel or get disturbed when insects eat my body in the grave?

Tags: death, soul

Is there any hadith from the prophet Mohammad (S.A.W) that any believer or disbeliever feel when their body is being eaten in the grave? If so, what are the effects on the soul and how the soul feels it?

Is there anything the believer can do when he/she is alive to avoid this very thing in the grave?

Comment: Once you're in the grave, insects consuming your body will be the least of your worries. If you are going to heaven, you'll be too happy, perhaps in a euphoric state (maybe, Allah knows best) that you won't even feel anything. If you're going to hell, you'll be too scared and feeling painful and sorry, that you'd wish that being consumed by insects is the only pain you're feeling,... but it's not. May Allah have mercy on us all.

Answer (score 1):

What happens in the grave to believers or disbelievers is a matter of *ghaib* (unseen, non-attendance) that we only come to know of through verses of the Qur'an or authenticated hadiths of the Prophet ﷺ, neither of which address any of your questions. We do not know if a buried body feels the decay process of their body; and if it is the case, we do not know of its effects on the soul, or of any special deeds that would ward off such effect.

Answer (score 0):

nope you'll be in a room allah can give the sane body again too don't worry for the believer and good doers there will be a garden of paradise in his grave i think and for the sinner and disbeliever jahannam some of it don't worry allah is wise in power

Comment: This answer could use some evidences to support your claims (see [answer]).

Answer (score 0):

I think, the the insects are least of your worries. There are much worse torments.

When you are in Grave and if you had been a good person, then you won’t even think about that, because you’ll see your place in Heaven and as for disbeliever, it is worse much torment. And do not worry about your body, because God Almighty Says:

> “And the Trumpet will be blown (i.e.  the second blowing) and behold!  From the graves they will come out quickly to their Lord.” (Quran 36:51)

This means that, your body will be restored after it has been decayed. So don’t for this, just, stay relaxed and fulfill the job that God has given you to do and that’s it.